Swiftui button with underline on image and characters
I want to create a button in SwiftUI that has the following features.

The button text should start with an image.
The image is the part of the text in the label. It should appear as if the first character is the image.
The text could be multiline.
All the text characters as well as the image should be underlined.



Text also supports attaching an Image. You can try this approach:
Group {
    Text(Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up"))
    + Text("This is a button along with the line")
}
.underline(true)

Output:

